# Dynamically change the column name of the database and store values into it in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my view page, i have hash of data in the format

```
"round"=>{"1"=>"a", "2"=>"b", "3"=>"c", "4"=>"d"}
```

and I have four columns `round1,round2,round3 and round4`

Now dynamically I am storing these hash values into the these 4 columns.

I am following the following way

```
if params[:round].present?
    count=1
    params[:round].each do |k,v|
      @data.("round"+"#{count}")=v
      count+=1
    end
  end
```

here `@data=MgData.new()`

in the above code, i want to save it as `@data.round1=v,@data.round2=v....` but im ending up with error

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: For every loop, it should save like `@data.round1=a, @data.round2=b...`

Comment: **Describe the problem.** Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your this line : `@data.("round"+"#{count}")=v` is causing the error

This is how you should be assigning attributes dynamically

```
if params[:round].present?
  params[:round].each do |k,v|
    @data.send("round#{k}=", v)
  end
end
```

Comment: they should also really not be using count, but instead `@data.send("round#{k}=", v)`